# C# WPF Drawing a Curly Brace using graphics - any available implementations?

Tags: wpf, graphics

I need to draw pictures of machines with curly braces inserted to show where measurements are made on the machine parts (diameter etc).

I can draw it 'in hand' but it seems like something that others have done before me? It's hard to find something meaningful when you google "c# Draw Braces" ;-)

Does anyone know of a library that allows for easy drawing of braces? Or just make the calculation of points?

Thanks for any comments,

Anders, Denmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at FormattedText.BuildGeometry:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.buildgeometry.aspx

You can give it a curly brace, and it will return a geometry. You can then render this as a Path.

Comment: Ah, maybe I wasn't specific enough - the drawn brace needs to be between specific points showing e.g. where on a drawing the diameter is found. A brace from formattedText would not give me that option?

Comment: It would give you a geometry, you can then use this as the geometry of your path. You are then free to scale your path however you like. Just set its stretch property and the width / height you require.

Comment: I ended up getting a breaktrough with a 'manual' implementation instead. As for answer, I was looking for suggestions for libraries, so I'm afraid I wouldn't say the suggestion is really an answer to the question. Sorry...

Comment: If you have your own correct answer please add it for everyone else, and mark it as correct.

Comment: It's a bit elaborate to submit my entire implementation, but basically, I drew the braces using a quarter-circle at each end of the brace and two quarter-circles in the middle to form the 'pointer'. I've marked ColinE's answer as - thinking about it - you **could** say the WPF is the sought-after library...

Comment: You should add your answer @AndersJuul as ColinE's answer is not really an answer at all.